# Proof of the wrong limit with Epsilon-Delta method

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I am a university student and we learned about 'Formal Definition of Limit' this week.

Now I have a question about that topic, and it prevents me to understand the concept.

For example, we can prove a limit we know is true that way;

$$\begin{align*}
&\lim_{x\to3}2x+1=7\\
&to\:prove\:that;\\
&|f(x)-L|<\epsilon\\
&\Rightarrow|2x+1-7|<\epsilon\\
&\Rightarrow|2x-6|<\epsilon\\
&\Rightarrow2|x-3|<\epsilon\\
&\Rightarrow|x-3|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}
\end{align*}$$
So we can assume $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Now we can say there is a $\delta$ for every $\epsilon$. And is always greater than $|x-3|$. And so we can say the limit is true.

But what if we tried to proof a limit which we know it is already false.
$$\begin{align*}
&\lim_{x\to3}2x+1\not=8\\
&to\:prove\:that;\\
&|f(x)-L|<\epsilon\\
&\Rightarrow|2x+1-8|<\epsilon\\
&\Rightarrow|2x-7|<\epsilon\\
&\Rightarrow|2(x-3)-1|<\epsilon\\
&\Rightarrow-\epsilon<2(x-3)-1<\epsilon\\
&\Rightarrow-\epsilon+1<2(x-3)<\epsilon+1\\
&\Rightarrow\frac{-\epsilon+1}{2}<x-3<\frac{\epsilon+1}{2}
\end{align*}$$
In this example I couldn't finish it. How can we proof that this limit is not equal to 8?

Comment: If you want to prove $8$ is not the limit, you need to use the negation of the definition of limit. You need to find some specific $\epsilon>0$ s.t for every $\delta>0$ there is some $x$ such that $0<|x-3|<\delta$ but $|f(x)-8|\geq\epsilon$. It shouldn't be difficult to guess a possible $\epsilon$ here.

Comment: It's better just to prove the limit, if it exists, is unique.